# wxPython: prevent taskbar menu from closing after clicking an item

Tags: python, wxpython, taskbar

I am using wxPython to create a taskbar menu. The menu contains some menu items (obviously). 
Now I would like to update/change some of these items when a particular item is clicked, **while still displaying the menu**.

How can I prevent the taskbar menu from disappearing after clicking an item? 
The only method I've found that could be useful is [`wxMenu.UpdateUI()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxmenu.html#wxmenuupdateui), but that doesn't prevent the menu from disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Although I never got around to trying it myself, I remember attempting a similar effect with a popup menu & textctrl. You might want to consider trying [wx.lib.agw.flatmenu.FlatMenuBar](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.flatmenu.FlatMenuBar-class.html), it provides an event handler ***OnMenuDismissed(self, event)***, as well as a few others, which by name appear to be what you need. You would need to create your own OnMenuDismissed() and override the event.